# Show multiple picture from database php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image

I was wondering how to show more then one picture from the database on a php document. I know hoe to put a picture into mysql and take out one of them but i don't know how to take out multiple (or all). Thanks in advance.

One of my php files looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
</head>

<form action='pictureuploadtest.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
File: <input type='file' name='fileone'>
<input type = 'submit' name='submitfile'>
</form>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die("Cannot connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("testpicture") or die("Cannot connect to db: ".mysql_error());

$file = $_FILES['fileone']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file)) {
print "Choose an image";
} else {
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileone']['tmp_name']));
$imagename = addslashes($_FILES['fileone']['name']);
$imagesize = getimagesize($_FILES['fileone']['tmp_name']);


if($imagesize === false) {
echo "Invalid image.";
} else {
$insert = "INSERT INTO upload VALUES ('', '$imagename', '$image')";
if(mysql_query($insert, $con)) {
    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    echo "Image uploaded. <p /> Your image: <p /> <img src=getpic.php?id=$lastid width='300px' height='300px'>";
} else {
    echo "Cannot upload image: ".mysql_error();
}
}
}


?>

</html>
```

and then the getpic.php looks like this

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die("Cannot connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("testpicture") or die("Cannot connect to db: ".mysql_error());


$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];


echo $image;

?>
```

So this code can tell the user to upload an image then show that image after adding it to the database, but how can i show multiple or all pictures in the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do your self a favour  and don't put the images in the db, just their name\path

Comment: This is the right thing: don't store images in the DB. But I put a technical answer to your question below :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's some *very basic* code you can follow, but please read the **BOLD NOTE** at the end.

You could use multiple file inputs like this:

```
<input type='file' name='fileone'>
<input type='file' name='filetwo'>
...
```

and then you would call your insert for each file uploaded (or preferably loop, but this is more in line with the multiple inputs above):

```
$file = $_FILES['fileone']['tmp_name'];
... the rest of the insert code ...

$file = $_FILES['filetwo']['tmp_name'];
... the rest of the insert code ...
```

and then you would loop on the select when you pull the images out:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image)) {
... the rest of your fetch code ...
}
```

**BUT YOU SHOULD NEVER (almost never) STORE IMAGES IN A DATABASE!**

Images should be stored on the filesystem for a few reasons:

1. The filesystem will more efficient and faster: An image on a filesystem with a web server on the system can directly pull images straight from the filesystem to the webserver out to the user. In a database, it's more from the file system, through the database layer, (possibly over a network) to the web server and out to the user.
2. You don't want to bother your database )which can do all sorts of awesome and impressive things like joins and subselects - if it's not being wasted directly pulling big binary blobs of images) with something as trivial as storing and retrieving images.
3. It's less efficient (on disk space) to use a database, though this is really becoming less and less of an issue as storage costs approach 0.

Comment: There are numerous reasons to store images in a database...examples include Load Balanced environments (ie: multiple web servers) and simple record integrity as keeping a backup of a database server alone is far easier than keeping a backup of both a database server and file system in sync.

Comment: Load balancing a DB is much harder (on the server itself) than load balancing by simply adding another web server and doing some round robin passthroughs. You can use a shared or rsynced filesystem for that. The only real reason to use a DB is if you want to version your images and have a delete flag or something on them in a DB. The biggest sites on the internet use filesystems, not DBs for image storage. Best practice. (this has been answered a lot on stackoverflow)

Comment: So i am not quite sure what the double input does and how that will affect code. Also, what would i do if i wanted to show them on a different page. Thanks again. @MattPavelle

Comment: Hi @user2433384 - so having two inputs was just a *very* basic way to illustrate how you could upload two images at once. Essentially your HTML form would have two places to choose files to upload. Then when you're saving to the database you would save both (best to check that there is a value for each), etc. If you wanted to show each on a different page, you'd probably want to use logic to dictate which image shows on which page, but that's getting away from a simple question and more into "please build this for me" territory :)